# HyperLedger-Fabric ChainCode Deployment Giving Parse Error

Tags: unmarshalling, blockchain, hyperledger, peer, hyperledger-fabric

I have setup a peer in a vm and its running fine. Also i have registered the chaincode with the peer through this

> CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=chaincode_example02 CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:51011 ./chaincode_example02

and it showed no error

Now after this when i try to hit the init method from rest using this json

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID":{
        "name": "chaincode_example02",
         "path": "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
        "function":"init",
        "args": ["a","100","b","200"]
    }
  },
  "id": 10
}
```

i get this error

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
  "error": {
    "code": -32700
    "message": "Parse error"
    "data": "Error unmarshalling chaincode request payload: illegal base64 data at input byte 0"
  }-
  "id": null
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: When I run this code, the peer logs say `Failed to init chaincode(handler not found for chaincode chaincode_example02)`, so clearly the init is failing for whatever reason. Do you get the same error message popping up on your peer when you try to deploy the chaincode? Could you please provide the section of the peer logs where it is dealing with this deployment?

Comment: no i didnt get this error , but for me init is not working with the above given error and after i have registered , i am not getting any updates on init, invoke or anything. Also one more thing when peer is running, it keeps on giving me a message after certain lntervals that " grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp ipaddr:port no : getsockopt: no route to host"; Reconnecting to ":ipaddr:port no""

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Following is what I've done and returned message. Please find my traffic log captured by tcpdump in the attached screenshot. Looks like nothing has been actually transferred except for controlling signals [image]

1. I started a validating peer running noops consensus with this command in 1st terminal console

   docker run --name vp0 --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock -p 7050:7050 -p 7051:7051 -p 7054:7054 -p 7053:7053 -e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true hyperledger/fabric-peer peer node start
2. I register the example chaincode with these commands in 2nd terminal console

   cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02

   go build

   CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincode_example02
3. the 1st terminal console show that my example chaincode got registered

   18:32:12.070 [chaincode] HandleChaincodeStream -> DEBU 061 Current context deadline = 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC, ok = false

   18:32:12.071 [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 062 []Received message REGISTER from shim

   18:32:12.071 [chaincode] HandleMessage -> DEBU 063 []Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTER in state created

   18:32:12.071 [chaincode] beforeRegisterEvent -> DEBU 064 Received REGISTER in state created

   18:32:12.071 [chaincode] registerHandler -> DEBU 065 registered handler complete for chaincode mycc

   18:32:12.071 [chaincode] beforeRegisterEvent -> DEBU 066 Got REGISTER for chaincodeID = name:"mycc" , sending back REGISTERED

   18:32:12.071 [chaincode] notifyDuringStartup -> DEBU 067 nothing to notify (dev mode ?)
4. the 2nd terminal console says everything seems to be fine

   18:32:12.069 [shim] DEBU : Peer address: 0.0.0.0:7051

   18:32:12.070 [shim] DEBU : os.Args returns: [./chaincode_example02]

   18:32:12.070 [shim] DEBU : Registering.. sending REGISTER

   18:32:12.071 [shim] DEBU : []Received message REGISTERED from shim

   18:32:12.071 [shim] DEBU : []Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTERED(state:created)

   18:32:12.071 [shim] DEBU : Received REGISTERED, ready for invocations
5. When I deploy the example chaincode to the peer, I got the error message

   peer chaincode deploy -n mycc -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'

   19:03:33.715 [logging] LoggingInit -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'chaincode'
   Error: Chaincode argument error: illegal base64 data at input byte 0

Comment: are you getting any updates on the terminal after it is registered whenver you are calling init or invoke?

Comment: and also are you getting any sort of message in the logs when your peer is running like this one? " grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp ipAddr:portNo: getsockopt: no route to host"; Reconnecting to "ippadrr: portNo""

Comment: I didn't run "init" or "invoke" since it failed to deploy at first place.
I ended up build from the latest source cloned from github and run single peer in dev mode.