# HyperLedger-Fabric ChainCode Deployment - Base64 error

Tags: go, unmarshalling, hyperledger

I was trying to setup the Hyperledger blocchain on my laptop by following the Windows setup , was able to bring the docker images up and running, but when I try to deploy the examples provided, it always throws back the error in the JSON input as shown below.

```
peer chaincode deploy -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'
```

response:

```
sug@sri-ub:~/go/$ docker exec -it aa413f4c4289 bash
root@aa413f4c4289:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric# peer chaincode deploy -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'

04:30:55.822 [logging] LoggingInit -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'chaincode' Error: Non-empty JSON chaincode parameters must contain exactly 1 key: 'Args'
```

I tried in POSTMAN from the HOST machine:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"deploy","params":{"type":1,"chaincodeID":{"path":"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02"},"ctorMsg":{"function":"init","args":["a", "1000", "b", "2000"]}},"id":1}
```

got the response as

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error","data":"Error unmarshalling chaincode request payload: illegal base64 data at input byte 0"},"
```

This is similar to the error message and I couldn't resolve this still, creating a new post as advised, please help me fix this issue.

[Similar issue reported  but that also doesn't answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918739/hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-deployment-giving-parse-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In latest fabric's version the request's format was changed. Function name should be in Args and all parameters should be base64 encoded.
Instead of:

`{"function":"init","args":["a", "1000", "b", "2000"]}}`

The arguments for deploy command will look like:

`{"args":['aW5pdA==', 'YQ==', 'MTAwMA==', 'Yg==', 'MjAwMA==']}`

**Update**: Format was changed again. Base64 encoding is not necessary any longer. correct payload in latest Fabric is:

`{“args”:['init', 'a', '100', 'b', '100']}`

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey!, its working fine. Here is the actual code 

`{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID":{
        "path":"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
   "args":["aW5pdA==", "YQ==", "MTAwMA==", "Yg==", "MjAwMA=="]
    }
    
    },
  "id": 1
  }`

Comment: Sergey, I see that both formats are supported:
`{"function":"init","args":["a", "1000", "b", "2000"]}}`
as well as
`{"args":["init","a", "1000", "b", "2000"]}}`

Comment: @Mil4n Hmm, that is right. It looks like both formats are supported now. Just tested with “function, args” and just “args” and both requests were accepted. Thank you for info.