# unmarshalling error in hyperledger's REST API?

Tags: rest, hyperledger

I sent this request to hyperledger's REST API:

```
$ curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deploy", "params": { "type": 1, "chaincodeID":{ "path":"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02" }, "ctorMsg": { "args":["init", "a", "1000", "b", "2000"] } }, "id": 1 }' localhost:7050/chaincode
```

and this is the error message I got in return:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error","data":"Error unmarshalling chaincode request payload: illegal base64 data at input byte 0"},"id":null}
```

I then added debug log in rest_api.go to check whatever is received by the peer 
[image]
and got this log:

```
16:03:46.323 [rest] ProcessChaincode -> DEBU 027 reqBody = { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deploy", "params": { "type": 1, "chaincodeID":{ "path":"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02" }, "ctorMsg": { "args":["init", "a", "1000", "b", "2000"] } }, "id": 1 }
16:03:46.331 [rest] ProcessChaincode -> ERRO 028 Error unmarshalling chaincode request payload: illegal base64 data at input byte 0
```

The received message seems to match with the definition of "rpcRequest", "ChaincodeSpec", and "ChaincodeInput", I don't understand why it keeps throwing unmarshalling error to me...
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the issue is the same as:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050494/hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-deployment-base64-error

Comment: @SergeyBalashevich, thanks for the tips!